# Live vertical profile plot in imagej

Tags: image, imagej

In imageJ, it is possible to use the rectangular selection tool to select an area, and then use Control-K (I'm using a Mac, but I think this is the same on the PC) to take the horizontal profile. This opens a new window, where you can click on the "Live" button, which allows you to see how the horizontal profile changes as you change the selection or scroll through a stack of images.

I want to do the same thing with the vertical profile. It is possible to take the vertical profile of an image using Option-K (Alt-k on the PC?). However, when I click the "live" button, the profile reverts to the horizontal lineout option. Is this a bug? Anyway to get a live view of the vertical profile?

I have just been rotating the images, but often I have a very large stack of images and rotating them takes a very long time. Any suggestions?

Screenshot showing the real vertical profile (top right) and the vertical profile after clicking the "live" button (bottom right):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

- Set `Prefs.verticalProfile` to `true`:

  ```
  import ij.IJ;
  IJ.run("Profile Plot Options...", "width=450 height=200 minimum=0 maximum=0 vertical interpolate draw");
  ```

  or, on a lower level:

  ```
  import ij.Prefs;
  Prefs.verticalProfile = true;
  ```
- Enable *Vertical profile* in the *Edit > Options > Profile Plot Options...* dialog:
  [image: Profile Plot Options]
- You can use a [line selection](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-19.html#sub:Straight-Line-Selection) with [adjustable thickness](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:Line-WidthSlider). Press *Shift* while creating the selection to keep the line strictly vertical.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! The second and third methods work great. Is the first method equivalent to clicking the "Vertical profile" option in the Plot Profile Options window? I'm something of an imageJ newb, so I'm not actually sure how to run the code that you sent. Do I make it into a macro or something?

Comment: The code I posted was Java code, and it is the equivalent of clicking OK on the above dialog. You get the code by running *Plugins > Macros > Record...*, switching to the language you'd like to record (*Macro*, *JavaScript*, *BeanShell* or *Java*) and then running *Edit > Options > Profile Plot Options...*